# select multiple columns using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am new to python and trying to read excel file using openpyxl.

My Excel file has 20 columns and I need to only extract the 5 columns .

My Excel file

```
      CustNumber CustName Serial Number CreateDate ModifiedDate Organization CustAddress Phone
         1       XYZ       1010         01-01-2021   01-10-2021    test1     101 parklane  234
         2       ABC       1012         01-01-2021   01-10-2021    test2     102 texchlane 234
         3       CDF        1010         01-01-2021   01-10-2021   test1     101 parklane  234
         4       ASC       1012         01-01-2021   01-10-2021    test2     102 texchlane 234
```

Output

```
   CustNumber CustName              CreateDate ModifiedDate Organization    CustAddress 
         1       XYZ                01-01-2021   01-10-2021    test1     101 parklane  
         3       CDF                01-01-2021   01-10-2021    test1     101 parklane
```

I need to select some columns from the excel file and filter the records in the excel file where Organization = test1.

I want to do it in openpyxl not in pandas.I am able to read one column but not sure how can I read multiple columns and then filter the file to extract only test1 records.

My code

```
  import openpyxl
  book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
  sheet = book['SSH_CERT']
  column_name = 'Description'
  for column_cell in sheet.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column): 
  if column_cell[0].value == column_name:    
   j = 0
    for data in column_cell[1:]:   
        print(data.value)
    break
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would be 1 line of code with pandas but since you want the openpyxl solution here it is:

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = book['SSH_CERT']
# enter column names you want to be removed
column_names = ['CreatedDate']
for cell in sheet[1]:
    if cell.value in column_names:
        sheet.delete_cols(cell.column, 1)

book.save(filename='book1_res.xlsx')
```

This searches all columns and removes anything stored in `column_names`